# How are Distributed Denial Of Service (DDOS) attacks resovled

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

I just realised that I don't know how (denial) of service attacks are resolved especially in the long term.

The attacking machines don't get tired and there must be some cooperation involved in dealing with the attack.

How is an attack dealt with long term? Can a company under attack call some kind of special phone number? If an attack is from another country, how do people who deal with these attack cooperate?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you can only prevent a DOS attack, especially during a Distributed Denial-Of-Service attack, as many **Botnet** computers or even Bot-Free computers causing the problem lead to amounts of information too hard to trace. Here are some methods of prevention:

**Application Front-End Hardware:**

- Buying intelligent hardware that can analyze data packets and determine which ones are safe and which are not.

**Bandwidth Management:**

- Controlling the amount of network traffic through methods such as throttling and server time-outs.

For more information, visit
[this website.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)